# Do subtitles not work if there's no speakers connected?

Tags: borderlands

Do subtitles not work if there's no speakers connected on PC?

It seems like that's why I'm not seeing them, but I'm not sure.

However, the sound seems to be trying to play, since it doesn't skip dialogue?

I'm using Bluetooth Headphones, and when they're connected and playing sound, I do see the subtitles.

Comment: Really obvious question, but do you actually have subtitles enabled in the game? Have you seen them before? And finally, does it work when you DO plug in speakers/headphones?

Comment: @BoffinBrain - Yes, Yes, and Yes. I'll move that out of being implied...

Comment: How very strange... Well if it were me, I'd just plug in some headphones and turn the volume all the way down to work around the issue. Not really worthy of an answer, but if it works, it works!

Comment: @BoffinBrain - I was asking just in hope for some confirmation, as an answer, and then possibly some help. ... I forget if you try to replay ECHO logs, whether those do give subtitles for some reason...